# How to apply a tree-based model with numerical and categorical values to find outliers

Tags: machine-learning, python, outlier, isolation-forest

I have a dataset which has a column of prices, a column of dates, and various other columns of numerical and categorical values. I would like to find outlier prices based on all the columns in the dataset, and to this end I have settled on using an isolation forest. The question I have though is how do I find outlier prices using an isolation forest?

As an example, I have a dataframe `iso_df` with 5 columns: `PRICE` is a column of prices which I want to find outliers for, `RIV_VALUES` is a second column of prices (but I don't want to find outliers for this), `ITEM_GROUP` is a categorical column with values such as `A`, `B`, `C`, etc., and `YEAR_MONTH` is a column of year-month combinations (e.g. `2020-01`, `2020-02`, etc.) so the example dataframe looks like this:

```
  PRICE    |   RIV_VALUES   |  ITEM_GROUP  |    YEAR_MONTH
---------------------------------------------------------------
    2.2    |      4.7       |       A      |     2020-01
    7.9    |      3.9       |       A      |     2020-02  
     2     |      1.2       |       B      |     2020-01
    10.2   |      8.9       |       A      |     2020-03
    25.2   |      2.4       |       D      |     2020-02
```

i.e.

```
iso_df = iso_df[['PRICE', "RIV_VALUES", "ITEM_GROUP", 'YEAR_MONTH']]
```

After this, I use `label_encoder` from the `scikit-learn` package to transform the `ITEM_GROUP` and `YEAR_MONTH` columns to ordinal numerical values.

Once that is done, my idea was doing something like this:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import IsolationForest

clf = IsolationForest(n_estimators = 10, max_samples='auto', contamination=float(.05), max_features=1.0, bootstrap=False, n_jobs=-1, verbose=0)
clf_prediction = clf.fit_predict(iso_df)
```

However, this feels incorrect to me - since I'm trying to find `PRICES` which are outliers, should I still combine it all in the model like this? Or should I find a way to separate them more? Or alternatively, is there a better model to do this with (besides the usual confidence interval/box plot approaches). Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that you have a level feature, `ÌTEM_GROPUP`. It implies that what may be considered an outlier for category `A` may not be for category `B` or `C`. You could make some descriptive analysis of each category to check how similar the distribution for each category is.

You may have some alternatives:

1. Treat the problem as a [time series anomaly detection](https://neptune.ai/blog/anomaly-detection-in-time-series) where you will have the historical prices over time, so you will only include `PRICE` in your model.
2. If you have enough data for every category, you could train an independent anomaly detection model for each category. So in the inference stage, you will first check the new point's category and then apply the corresponding model.

I hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Regarding your comment about the `ITEM_GROUP` column, wouldn't the Isolation Forest be able to do that for me? I was under the impression that since Isolation Forests can work with categorical data, they can determine outliers based on each individual category (i.e. `A`, `B`, etc.), or is my understanding wrong? If my understanding is indeed incorrect, then I will definitely try out your second alternative!